# How do I find the permanent url for photos shared publicly on a google+ event

Tags: google-plus, url, photo-sharing

I uploaded some photos to a Google+ event. Google+ states that they are shared publicly.

I click the link on the event page to see them and would expect to be able to use the URL in the address bar to share the links outside of google+ e.g. on twitter or on a website.

Then people who aren't logged in on Google+ should be able to see the link.

However, when I test this and visit the link, the page is blank.

Please advise on the URL to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further checking and found that the photo album is only visible to event attendees. However, the photos can be viewed if the event is made public and if people first visit the event via this public URL and then click through to the photos (the direct link to the photo album would still not be public).

Answer (score 0):

Open a new browser window and switch to Incognito mode.

Now open the event's photo album ([example](https://plus.google.com/events/gallery/coimpouj5kbvis1mqcohq4oq0so)) in this instance of the browser and click on any photo. Copy the permalink of that photo from the browser's address bar. ([example](https://plus.google.com/events/gallery/coimpouj5kbvis1mqcohq4oq0so?pid=5894576880795427794&oid=101485436043392788426))

Comment: I tried your example and I still get a blank page whereby I only see a few options on the top and no photos. I think this is because the photos are only shared with those who can see the event and not the public (this applies to my photos in my example as well your example.)

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and it worked. Also that event in that example is public.

Comment: did you also test and find it worked when *logged* out of *all* of your google accounts? If not, please try this and confirm - 1) copy the URL of the photo album (to the clipboard or a text editor). Then log out completely from all google accounts. To be sure, go into settings and clear all history, cookies data, all boxes checked, time period: from the beginning 3) paste that copied URL in step 1) into chrome.